# Undefined/Redefined Error with premade Methods in MPLAB v8.92 when working with a PIC18F4620

Tags: c, assembly, methods, mplab, pic18

this is my first question, so please let me know how I could possibly ask the question better.

I am working with MPLAB v8.92 for an Embedded Systems class. My teacher gave me some pre-written C code that is used to output to a LCD display connected to our PIC Board. The issue is that when I try and run any code that uses these premade methods, it either gives me a Undefined or Redefined error.

(This is using the Hi-TECH Universal ToolSuite C Complier)

```
// --------- LCD_PortD.C ---------------------
//
// This routine has LCD driver routines
//
//  LCD_INST:   send an instruction to the LCD
//  LCD_DATA:   send data to the LCD
//  LCD_INIT:   initialize the LCD to 16x4 mode
//
//--- Revision History -----------------
//     5/20/00   JSG
//     9/27/00   Modify LCD_HELLO for Jump messages
//    11/05/00   Clean up LCD routine to use less RAM
//    10/14/14   Modified for new PIC boards



void Wait_ms(unsigned int X)
{
   unsigned int i, j;

   for (i=0; i<X; i++)
      for (j=0; j<617; j++);
   }


void LCD_Pause(void)
{
   unsigned char x;
   for (x=0; x<20; x++);
   }


void LCD_Strobe(void)
{
   RD3 = 0;
   LCD_Pause();
   RD3 = 1;
   LCD_Pause();
   RD3 = 0;
   LCD_Pause();
   }
         
//  write a byte to the LCD in 4 bit mode 

void LCD_Inst(unsigned char c)
{
    RD2 = 0;        // send an instruction
    PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) |  (c & 0xF0);
    LCD_Strobe();
    PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) |  ((c<<4) & 0xF0);
    LCD_Strobe();
    Wait_ms(10);
}

void LCD_Move(unsigned char Row, unsigned char Col)
{
   if (Row == 0) LCD_Inst(0x80 + Col);
   if (Row == 1) LCD_Inst(0xC0 + Col);
   if (Row == 2) LCD_Inst(0x94 + Col);
   if (Row == 3) LCD_Inst(0xD4 + Col);
   }
   
void LCD_Write(unsigned char c)
{
    RD2 = 1;        // send data
    PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) |  (c & 0xF0);
    LCD_Strobe();
    PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) |  ((c<<4)  & 0xF0);
    LCD_Strobe();
    
}


void LCD_Init(void)
{
   TRISD = 0x01;       
   RD1 = 0;  
   LCD_Inst(0x33);
   LCD_Inst(0x32);
   LCD_Inst(0x28);
   LCD_Inst(0x0E);
   LCD_Inst(0x01);
   LCD_Inst(0x06);
   Wait_ms(100);
   }


void LCD_Out(long int DATA, unsigned char D, unsigned char N)
{
   unsigned char A[10], i;
   
   if(DATA < 0) {
      LCD_Write('-');
      DATA = -DATA;
      }
   else LCD_Write(' ');
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      A[i] = DATA % 10;
      DATA = DATA / 10;
   }
   for (i=D; i>0; i--) {
      if (i == N) LCD_Write('.');
      LCD_Write(A[i-1] + '0');
   }
}

void SCI_Out(long int DATA, unsigned char D, unsigned char N)
{
   unsigned char A[10], i;

   while(!TRMT);   
   if(DATA < 0) {
      TXREG = '-';
      DATA = -DATA;
      }
   else TXREG = ' ';
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      A[i] = DATA % 10;
      DATA = DATA / 10;
      }
   for (i=D; i>0; i--) {
      if (i == N) { while(!TRMT); TXREG = '.'; }
      while(!TRMT);  TXREG = A[i-1] + 48;
      }
   }


void SCI_CRLF(void)
{
   while(!TRMT);  TXREG = 13;
   while(!TRMT);  TXREG = 10;
   }
```

The errors I get are:

```
HI-TECH C PRO for the PIC18 MCU Family (Lite)  V9.63PL3
Copyright (C) 1984-2009 HI-TECH SOFTWARE
(1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Lite mode (warning)
Advisory[1233] Employing 18F4620 errata work-arounds:
Advisory[1234]  * Corrupted fast interrupt shadow registers
Advisory[1234]  * Data in RAM location can be corrupted if async. reset occurs during write
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 18. function "_Wait_ms" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 27. function "_LCD_Pause" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 34. function "_LCD_Strobe" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 46. function "_LCD_Inst" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 56. function "_LCD_Move" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 64. function "_LCD_Write" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 75. function "_LCD_Init" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 89. function "_LCD_Out" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 108. function "_SCI_Out" redefined
Error   [237] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 129. function "_SCI_CRLF" redefined
```

or,

```
Make: The target "H:\Embedded Systems\Homework 5\LED Flashlight\Flashlight.p1" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-18\PRO\9.63\bin\picc18.exe" --pass1 "H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\Flashlight.c" -q --chip=18F4620 -P --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-download,+stackwarn,-config,+clib,-plib --opt=default,+asm,-speed,+space,9 --warn=0 -D__DEBUG=1 --mode=pro -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" 
Make: The target "H:\Embedded Systems\Homework 5\LED Flashlight\lcd_portd.p1" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-18\PRO\9.63\bin\picc18.exe" --pass1 "H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c" -q --chip=18F4620 -P --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-download,+stackwarn,-config,+clib,-plib --opt=default,+asm,-speed,+space,9 --warn=0 -D__DEBUG=1 --mode=pro -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" 
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 34.1 undefined identifier "RD3"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 46.1 undefined identifier "RD2"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 47.1 undefined identifier "PORTD"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 64.1 undefined identifier "RD2"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 65.1 undefined identifier "PORTD"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 75.1 undefined identifier "TRISD"
Error  [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 76.1 undefined identifier "RD1"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 110.8 undefined identifier "TRMT"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 112.1 undefined identifier "TXREG"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 115.6 undefined identifier "TXREG"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 129.8 undefined identifier "TRMT"
Error   [192] H:\Embedded Systems\Hex Files\lcd_portd.c; 129.15 undefined identifier "TXREG"
```

depending on whether or not I add a #include <pic18.h>

I need to use the LCD for a project, but I can't figure out how to use the pre-made methods,
any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could tell which command led to the first error output, and what the file `Flashlight.c` is.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi there, this looks like a header file issue. That's when you use the same header files within others, and you add those nested headers to your main, the compiler will include headers multiple times hence some definitions may be redefined. Can you show us you project's directory and file structure?